# Tracking uniqueness in nosql

Tags: nosql

Currently I'm working on a project where a user can belong to a group, and multiple users can possibly belong to the same group. A user can drop out of a group at anytime, and multiple groups can be named the same way. The problem I'm facing is keeping track of the uniqueness of groups. For instance, if two groups are named the same way, how do I distinguish the two without the concept of an id.

Example of what I mean:

```
{userName: 'user1', group: 'test' },
{userName: 'user2', group: 'test' },
{userName: 'user3, group: 'test' }
```

How do I know that all three 'test' groups refer to the same group. In sql, this is easily resolved by a unique Id. It seems much harder to id the groups in this case. This data seems more relational, maybe I'm better off sticking with a sql database?

Comment: What are your reasons for using a nosql database over rdbms?

Comment: In many cases, the database schema is quite simple, so it's easier to use light NoSQL DB istead of monstrous Oracle which will be used only on 10-15 percents. Also, in most cases scaling of NoSQL DB more easy than RDBMS.

Comment: I think that comment is a little inflammatory 'monstrous oracle'.  From his question he seems to be forcing a relational db model onto sql, the majority of the time you are best off with RDBMS.  Saying scaling is easier isn't really a valid comment for when he is discussing modelling his data.

Comment: It is quite possible that there are only quite a few levels of connectedness. In this case, relational problem very simply allowed in the manner which I have listed below. Given that the perfomance of the NoSQL DB is often higher RDBMS, support relational own hands is not such a big price. NoSQL does not mean "No relational". There is almost no not connecting data. Just the relationships between entities are not in usual format rows and columns.

Comment: 95% of the time RDBMS databases will be performant enough, data modeling is a lot easier in SQL and has been around for decades. The poster hasn't asked about scalability but about data modeling.

Comment: And I answered poster's question. And you asked him why he doesn't want to use RDBMS. Then began a Holy war. If you are easier to data modeling in a relational database, your right, but this does not mean that it is easier for everyone. Just nosql is not taught at the university, so many of his fear. I think it's best to end this discussion in this thread.

Comment: I honestly didn't have a good reason of using a nosql database except for just wanting to learn more about them and their benefits. Sadly, the problem I picked wasn't well suited for a nosql database. I'll try using it again with one of more 'schema-less' projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you use a document-oriented NoSql DB. So you can try following scheme. Let's "user1" is id for **{userName: 'user1', group: 'test' }**, "user2" is id for **{userName: 'user2', group: 'test' }**. You can create document with id "test1", which will contains id's of documents with users. For example: test1: **{users:[user1, user2]}**. When you insert new user to DB, you should to update document test1.

Comment: Ah thank you, this definitely answers the question. Although, after reading the comments above, I've realized that this problem is really suited for a relational database.